# O que é um nó (node) em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Me deparei com esse termo *nó* ou *node* em *JavaScript* no site do [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) o que seria isso?

**NOTA:** não me refiro a plataforma de aplicação **node.js**.

Comment: Se você entender inglês, esse vídeo pode te ajudar: [JavaScript Tutorial - Node - nodeName,nodeType and nodeValue properties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-w6EoPM0F5g)

Comment: Para entender o conceito de nós, você vai precisar estudar uma estrutura de dados chamada "árvore". O navegador guarda a página em uma estrutura de árvore chamada [DOMTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). Este é um bom ponto inicial para você começar a entender.

Comment: Relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974621/what-is-a-node-in-javascript

Comment: Então um nó seria qualquer elemento HTML dentro da árvore DOM?